# Display images by url in google app maker

Tags: google-drive-api, google-app-maker

I have a model with url images in this format "https://drive.google.com/file/d/< id >/view".

Urls are referred to images stored on my Drive.

I have an image widget into form binding  to the url in images model.

When I preview the app, the url works as  href but  image is not displayed in the form.

What's wrong? Someone can help me please?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the machine that is requesting the URL is not authorised to view the content on your drive.

Do you have a snippet of code you can share on here please?
You can edit your question to include this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Images Sample](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/images/)(https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/images/), it does exactly what you want. Just in case, the 'prestige' of that sample is hidden behind this line of code in `onCreate` method of the `DriveImage` model:

`record.ImageUrl = Drive.Files.get(record.Id).webContentLink;`